# JavaFX binding StringProperty and IntegerProperty

Tags: binding, javafx

I have a question about binding in JavaFX. Let's say I have mapping 1:"Aaa", 2:"Bbb", 3:"Ccc" and so on. What I want is to bind (bidirectional) 2 properties IntegerProperty and StringProperty according to this mapping. How this can be achieved?

**UPD:** I'll try to describe my use case. I have a class

```
class A {
   IntegerProperty num;
   ...
}
```

But in the user interface I want to show not this numerical value but some meaningful string. So I want to add `StringProperty numValue` and bind `num` and `numValue`. In table I'll use `numValue` as property for TableColumn. And when user change value of `numValue` (via combobox for example) I want `num` automatically update.

Comment: Why do you need to bind something?  Is it because the mapping can change?  e.g. 2: "Bbb" might become 2: "Zzz"?  And what are you binding with your two properties - a single map entry, e.g. 2: "Bbb"?  Because with just 2 properties you could not bind to an entire map.

Comment: I guess, even if you restrict your properties binding a single map entry, it is a still a bit vague, because a map can have two values the same for two different keys, e.g. one:many.  If you have 2: "Bbb" and 3: "Bbb" what is your corresponding bound integer value for "Bbb"?  You probably need to work on your question a little bit to specify it more precisely.  It is an interesting question though...  Maybe add some code which demonstrates thoroughly how you would use the API if it was available.

Comment: I update my question with description of my use case. Solution proposed by Tomas Mikula helped me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend to avoid bidirectional bindings if you can, they are problematic<sup>1</sup>.

If you really need a bidirectional binding, then you are lucky that one of your types is `String`. There is the [bindBidirectional](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#bindBidirectional-javafx.beans.property.Property-javafx.beans.property.Property-javafx.util.StringConverter-) method that let's you specify a `StringConverter` used to convert between a `String` and the other type `T`, in your case `Integer`.

```
Map<Integer, String> m = ...;
StringProperty sp = ...;
IntegerProperty ip = ...;

Bindings.bindBidirectional(sp, ip, new StringConverter<Number>() {

    @Override
    public Integer fromString(String s) {
        for(Integer key: m.keySet()) {
            if(m.get(key).equals(s)) {
                return key;
            }
        }
        return -1; // or whatever makes sense for you
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(Integer i) {
        return m.get(i);
    }
});
```

Why this is supported for types `String` and `T` and not for arbitrary types `T` and `U` is a mystery for me.

**In more general terms,** you have two types, `T`, `U`, and two functions, `f: T -> U` and `g: U -> T`, and then you want to establish a bidirectional binding between `Property<T>` and `Property<U>` using these two functions. In the above example, both `f` and `g` are realized by the `StringConverter` (for example, `f` is `fromString` and `g` is `toString`). You can establish such a bidirectional binding using [ReactFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/ReactFX)'s `Var`s<sup>2</sup>:

```
Function<T, U> f = ...;
Function<U, T> g = ...;
Var<T> vt = ...;
Var<U> vu = ...;

Var<U> vu1 = vt.map(f).asVar(u -> vt.setValue(g.apply(u)));
Bindings.bindBidirectional(vu, vu1);
```

You don't necessarily need `f` to be the inverse of `g`, i.e. you don't need `g(f(x)) = x`, but in order to avoid infinite loop (stack overflow), it better converge quickly, for example `f(g(f(x))) = f(x)`, or `g(f(g(f(g(f(g(f(x)))))))) = g(f(g(f(g(f(x))))))` or something like that.

---

<sup>1</sup> I realize I just threw this statement in without providing any valid argument.
<sup>2</sup> `Var` is really just a `Property` with some extra methods.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I need. Why do you think bidirectional mapping problematic? I've describe my use case in question. Do you think I can have some problems?